# split string into two arrays one int and one string

Tags: java

I have to write a method that will get a `String` like "Mike 40 Mark 59 Rita 99" and splits it into two arrays, one will be `String` array and another will be `int` array. The output should be following:

```
Mike    40,
Mark    59,
Rita    99,
```

Here is what I have, I am very new and stuck here. Please, help, it will be greatly appreciated.

```
public static String[] getNames(){
   String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Enter one or more names");
   return s.split(" \\s+")
```

Comment: If you know the format of the original `String`, simple split it on " " (space) then loop through it, every second element is going to be a number.

Comment: I agree. I got the answer, should I post it?

Comment: Yes, it is. Could you please post it?

Comment: I did post it. I'm new to stackoverflow, thought they were against homework, but people don't seem to care.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your logic like following:

```
String input = "Mike 40 Mark 59 Rita 99";
String[] arr =  input.split(" ");

List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(String element : arr){
    if(elementIsnumber()) // write your logic to check its int or string
     {
        intList.add(parseInt(element)); // write to parse string to int here  
     }
    else{
      stringList.add(element);
     }
}

String[] srtingArray = stringList.toArray(new String[0]);
int[]  intArray =  intList.toArray(new int[0]);
```

Comment: I agree, but I do not know What the user would enter.

Comment: Its all right because user can be enter either int or string as input. So this will take care of it.